# How to mimic stopPropagation using jQuery.live

Tags: ajax, jquery

So I know that one of the downsides of using `jQuery.live` is the unavailability of `.stopPropagation()`. But I need it badly.

Here's my use case. I have a checkbox is that is currently bound to a click. However, other checkboxes appear on-screen via an AJAX call, meaning I really need `.live('click', fn)`. Unfortunately, the checkbox is situated atop another clickable element, requiring `.stopPropagation()`. This works fine with `.bind('click', fn)`, but the inability to use it with `.live()` is hampering me. Using `return false` doesn't work as the checkbox will not be checked.

Any ideas on how to mimic `.stopPropagation()` when using `.live()` without returning false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding a `.live` handler to the checkboxes, bind a smarter event handler to the container, with behaviour dependent on *which* element is the *target* of the event.

```
$("#container").click(function(e) {
    var ele = e.target;
    if(ele.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' 
        && ele.type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // do something special for contained checkboxes
        // e.g.:
        var val = $(ele).val();
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/g5bn4/) is something of an example to show how this can be used.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite works. Check out my update and see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/g5bn4/3/. I'm adding a checkbox using `jQuery.live()` and changed your IDs to classes so I could use two. Clicking the checkbox does not allow the call to `e.stopPropagation` to occur.

Comment: @Josh - Use `bind` on an outer container which is *not* replaced by your ajax call. See http://jsfiddle.net/g5bn4/7/